# Connect to Mongo via PHP

Tags: php, mongodb, openshift

I have an OpenShift Dev. account. I just installed Mongo and RockMongo. I am not running node.js.

Off of the RockMongo interface they have a link to this:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php

I have come up with the following PHP simply to try and connect:

```
//$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://admin:password@mysubdomain.rhcloud.com:27017" ); // connect to a remote host (default port: 27017)

$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://admin:password@localhost:27017" ); // connect to a remote host (default port: 27017)
```

I then get a, "500 (Internal Server Error)"

I have tried many snippets of code all one-liners to connect to the mongo server and nothing has worked.

Is there a way to do this using PHP and Mongo?

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value

mongo.allow_empty_keys  0   0

mongo.chunk_size    262144  262144

mongo.cmd   $   $

mongo.default_host  localhost   localhost

mongo.default_port  27017   27017

mongo.is_master_interval    15  15

mongo.long_as_object    0   0

mongo.native_long   1   1

mongo.ping_interval 5   5
```

Comment: Do you see a `mongodb` section in the `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Directive Local Value Master Value
mongo.allow_empty_keys 0 0
mongo.chunk_size 262144 262144
mongo.cmd $ $
mongo.default_host localhost localhost
mongo.default_port 27017 27017
mongo.is_master_interval 15 15
mongo.long_as_object 0 0
mongo.native_long 1 1
mongo.ping_interval 5 5

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I believe with no more errors. Maybe this might help someone else.

In the RockMongo interface you will find:

```
Connection
Host    127.5.xxx.yyy
Port    27017
Username    ******
Password    ******
```

From there you can do this:

```
$connection = new MongoClient( "mongodb://admin:my_password-@127.5.xxx.yyy:27017" );
```

I have not generated any errors this time.

Jim